# How to get vector string size in java?

Tags: java, vector

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8aaA.png)
I'm new in Java and here is my question: I want to receive a size of string of two-dimensional vector like

```
for (int i = 0; i < all_conections.size(); i++)
{    
    for (int j = 0; j < all_conections(i).size(); j++)
    {
        Scanner number_s = new Scanner(System.in);
        number = number_s.nextInt();
        weights2.addElement(number);
    }
    weights.addElement(weights2);
}
```

But it doesn't work - error: cannot find symbol
for (int j = 0; j < all_conections(i).size(); j++)

Please, tell me how to fix it

Comment: "Cannot find symbol" means that you are using a name (variable name, method name etc.) that does not exist in the program. Maybe you have made a typo in the name. The error message tells you exactly what name the compiler doesn't understand, so look carefully at the error message and check what name exactly it doesn't understand.

Comment: The problem is in all_conections(i).size(); j++), but if I remove (i) - everything goes fine
                             ^

Comment: You are trying to use `all_conections` as if it is a method, but there is no method named `all_conections` in your program. It's hard to tell what it should be, because from what you posted we don't know what `all_conections` is.

Comment: Vector<Vector<Integer>> all_conections = new Vector<Vector<Integer>>();
all_conections is two-dimensional vector and the thing is that in this cycle I want to get each size of i-strings.

Comment: Then it should be `all_conections.get(i)` as littlecode says in his answer below. By the way: class `Vector` is a super-old class that you shouldn't use anymore. Use `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: Okay, I will try

Comment: Thanks for supplying additional information. It’s always to do that *as edits to the question itself* so we have everything in one place. Frankly no one wants to have to read through all the comments in order to understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

`j < all_conections(i)` should be `j<all_conections.get(i)` or `j < all_conections`

Comment: 1) error: bad operand types for binary operator '<'
            for (int j = 0; j < all_conections.get(i); j++)
  first type:  int
  second type: Vector<Integer>

2) error: cannot find symbol
            for (int j = 0; j < all_conections(i); j++)
                                ^
  symbol:   method all_conections(int)

Comment: I have written like this, but - error: bad operand types for binary operator '<'
            for (int j = 0; j < all_conections.get(i); j++)
                              ^
  first type:  int
  second type: Vector<Integer>

Comment: sorry for my bad English . I mean you should write like this : `j<all_conections.get(i).size()`